# MySQL 5.1.69 at CentOS 6.4 doesn't know enable-named-pipe?

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, wordpress, mysql5

Trying to install MySQL (for WordPress) on a CentOS 6.4 /64 bit server.

I have installed the `mysql-server-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64` package and executed the following commands:

```
# chkconfig mysqld on
# service mysqld start
# /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'xxxxx'
# /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Then I've noticed that `mysqld_safe` process
is listening at 0.0.0.0 and decided to change that -
so that my WordPress installation only uses
domain sockets (or unix pipes? not sure about the correct term).

So I've modified the `/etc/my.cnf` to:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
bind-address = localhost
skip-networking
enable-named-pipe

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

But now MySQL refuses to start:

```
# service mysqld restart
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

The  `/var/log/mysqld.log` contains:

```
 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown option '--enable-named-pipe'
 [ERROR] Aborting
  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I've searched Google and grepped
`/usr/share/mysql/*.cnf` for that directive,
but haven't found any hints there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No hints?

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
bind-address = localhost
skip-networking
enable-named-pipe <-------------------

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

According the [online documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html) for that version of MySQL:

```
--enable-named-pipe
Command-Line Format --enable-named-pipe
Option-File Format  enable-named-pipe
Platform Specific   windows  <--------------------
```

> Enable support for named pipes. This option can be used only with the mysqld-nt and mysqld-debug servers that support named-pipe connections.

Remove that setting from your `/etc/my.cnf` and restart the process.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know `mysqld-nt` means Windows-only

Comment: 5.7.19 on a Mac. Don't know why I had this option in my cnf file.  Installed fresh, but maybe I configured it like I do on windows systems, but don't even recognize the -nt executable.  Commenting it works fine now, even my client connects over a socket still.